# Trouble with Observable of array of strings and Proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I have a simple Retrofit2 service

```
public interface PlaylistService {
    @GET("/machines/{uid}/playlist")
    Observable<List<String>> getPlaylist(@Path("uid") String uid);
}
```

When I use Proguard to minify, I get this error

> Observable return type must be parameterized as Observable or Observable<? extends Foo>

My Proguard file is empty. Do I need to put some keep class for String?

I'm also using Gson, but it is also for a list of string (List).

Comment: Can you share the class that has the `getPlaylist` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use retrofit proguard settings

```
# Retrofit does reflection on generic parameters. InnerClasses is required to use Signature and
# EnclosingMethod is required to use InnerClasses.
-keepattributes Signature, InnerClasses, EnclosingMethod

# Retrofit does reflection on method and parameter annotations.
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations, RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations

# Keep annotation default values (e.g., retrofit2.http.Field.encoded).
-keepattributes AnnotationDefault

# Retain service method parameters when optimizing.
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation interface * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}

# Ignore annotation used for build tooling.
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement

# Ignore JSR 305 annotations for embedding nullability information.
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

# Guarded by a NoClassDefFoundError try/catch and only used when on the classpath.
-dontwarn kotlin.Unit

# Top-level functions that can only be used by Kotlin.
-dontwarn retrofit2.KotlinExtensions
-dontwarn retrofit2.KotlinExtensions$*

# With R8 full mode, it sees no subtypes of Retrofit interfaces since they are created with a Proxy
# and replaces all potential values with null. Explicitly keeping the interfaces prevents this.
-if interface * { @retrofit2.http.* <methods>; }
-keep,allowobfuscation interface <1>

# Keep inherited services.
-if interface * { @retrofit2.http.* <methods>; }
-keep,allowobfuscation interface * extends <1>

# With R8 full mode generic signatures are stripped for classes that are not
# kept. Suspend functions are wrapped in continuations where the type argument
# is used.
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation

# R8 full mode strips generic signatures from return types if not kept.
-if interface * { @retrofit2.http.* public *** *(...); }
-keep,allowoptimization,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation class <3>
```

Comment: It looks like it worked, at least it build the aab. My question is: Why do I need to use these configs, should they not get imported from META-INF?

Comment: If you are using R8 the shrinking and obfuscation rules are included automatically. In other cases, you may need these rules.

Comment: An android APK file is actually a jar file (java archive), it is just a plain zip file with or without compression.

Comment: Jar files are used by all types of java applications, they have a specific structure - the META-INF folder contains the manifest information and other metadata about the java package carried by the jar file.